# How to merge folders of the same name when moving without loosing data in any folder, in Windows 7 ultimate x64?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, file-management

I use Windows 7 Ultimate x64. I want to move folders from my C drive to my D storage drive to save space in C. When the box comes up that asks if I want to merge or replace or skip moving a folder with the same name, if I merge them, do I replace one with the other? Could I be replacing a full folder with an empty folder? and loose my data? Or do I keep the contents of both folders? Or, how do I move and keep all contents. I go to the Edit subject, and choose "Move to folder..." and choose the folder. At some point that box usually comes up. I am a novice so need answers in 1st grade type language...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you will not loose any data. When you press **Yes** to the following dialogue box,[image: Merge]
It will simply move/copy all files to the folder. If both folders contain files of the same name, OS will ask for what to do, you may **replace the file**, **don't copy it** or **keep both in the new destination**.
**Caution:** Windows does not check the contents of a file, only the name. So, if you have two image files of same name but different content, os will treat them as similar files and ask for an option. If you click to replace the file, your file will be lost.

Comment: do you happen to know if merging checks for different files names in the two folders or does it check the file contents on similar files as well ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like AFAIK, it does not check the contens, only the file name+extension.

Comment: you are saying, if my source folder has a file **X.y** with content **ABC**, and destination has a file **X.y** with content **AB**, it will simply ignore the file while merging ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like It depends on the files being copied. When I copied two entirely different **.jpg** files, it simply asks to whether rename it or not. But, when I copied a modified/edited copy, it gave me three options: replace the file, don't copy it or keep both in the new destination.